# Find all notes which are not related to anything

Tags: contentdocumentlink, contentnote

We imported numerous notes into Salesforce and we were able to connect most of them to their corresponding objects with `ContentDocumentLink`. However, a few of need to be manually connected. So how can I list all notes which are not related to anything yet?

I tried querying all `ContentDocumentLink`s, but then I get the error message:

```
Implementation restriction: 
ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id 
on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator 
or multiple Id's using the IN operator.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a couple of things here.

**1.** You need the list of your `Opportunities`.

**2.** Then you need a list of the `ContentDocumentLinks` that are related to the Opportunities in that list.

**3.** Then we can get all `ContentNotes` that are not part of anything or related to any object.

```
    List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> contentDocutIds = new Set<Id>(); 

    for(Opportunity opp : oppList) {
        oppIds.add(opp.Id)
    }

    for(ContentDocumentLink conDocuments : [
         SELECT ContentDocumentId 
         FROM ContentDocumentLink 
         WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :oppIds]){
         contentDocutIds.add(conDocuments.ContentDocumentId);
     }

     // Now we get all parentless ContentNotes
     List<ContentNote> contentNotes = [SELECT Id FROM 
     ContentNote WHERE Id NOT IN: contentDocutIds];

     for(ContentNote conNote : contentNotes) {
      System.debug(conNote.Id);
     }
```

You can test this in a sandbox first if you want to. 
Create a new `ContentNote` using the **Developer Console**, **Execute Anonymous**:

```
ContentNote cn = new ContentNote();
cn.Title = 'test2';
String body = 'Hello World';
cn.Content = Blob.valueOf(body);
insert(cn);
```

Run the code on an **Execute Anonymous**:

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> contentDocutIds = new Set<Id>(); 

for(Opportunity opp : oppList) {
    oppIds.add(opp.Id)
}

for(ContentDocumentLink conDocuments : [
     SELECT ContentDocumentId 
     FROM ContentDocumentLink 
     WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :oppIds]){
     contentDocutIds.add(conDocuments.ContentDocumentId);
 }

 // Now we get all parentless ContentNotes
 List<ContentNote> contentNotes = [SELECT Id FROM 
 ContentNote WHERE Id NOT IN: contentDocutIds];

 for(ContentNote conNote : contentNotes) {
  System.debug(conNote.Id);
 }
```

Check output:
*In my case one new* `ContentNote`:

[image]

**UPDATE**

You probably want to do something like this then:
[Extract parent Id of ContentNotes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312299&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

This gets a bit complex because there is not a ParentId in the ContentNotes.

You can get all your ContentNotes like this:

```
List<ContentNote> contentNotes = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM ContentNote
];
```

Then you can pass the ids from that SOQL to strings like this:

```
List<String> stringIds = new List<String>();

for(ContentNote cn : contentNotes) {
    stringIds.add(String.valueOf(cn.Id));
}
```

Now that we have our ContentNotes ids we can do something like this:

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> clist = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.FileType, LinkedEntityId, ShareType, Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN : stringIds];
```

Now you can access the `LinkedEntityId` which it is the ParentId for the ContentNotes. But there is a catch here. This fields will keep track of the **Owner** and the **Related Object**.

This means that you can see one `ContentDocumentId` with two `LinkedEntityId`.

If you execute this on a execute anonymous window:

```
List<ContentNote> contentNotes = [
            SELECT Id
            FROM ContentNote
    ];

    List<String> stringIds = new List<String>();

    for(ContentNote cn : contentNotes) {
        stringIds.add(String.valueOf(cn.Id));
    }

List<ContentDocumentLink> clist = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.FileType, LinkedEntityId, ShareType, Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN : stringIds];
System.debug(clist);
```

You can get something similar to this if you have a ContentNote that is related to an SObject and one **that is not** (*except USER object*):

[image]

On the screenshot from above there is one `ContentNote` related to the `Account` object '`001`', and to the user object, '`005`'. The last `ContentDocumentLink` has only one `LinkedEntityId` starting with `005`.. user object.. perhaps you can use that as a way to find out which ContentNotes are not related to any SObjects, expect the User object.
On my test the last `ContentDocumentLink` is only connected to the user object, so I know that it is parentless to any other object.

I can see that there is a difference between the `ShareType` on `ContentDocumentLinks` that are related to a user and any other SObject. 
On the screenshot from above take a look to the `ShareType` for the two first records. The User have **I** on the `ShareType` and the other SObject has a **V**. You can explore that as well to see if it is something standard after creating a ContentNote.... well ... I hope it helps.

Comment: That's Classic Notes. If `ContentDocumentLink` is involved these records would be `ContentNote` or `ContentDocument` records.

Comment: Yes, you right.. let me change a few things to make this answer more accurate.

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo Cool, thx, but it's not quite right yet. I need all notes which aren't related to *anything*, not just not related to opportunities.

Comment: @adius, check the update... is not an easy task.. but I think that this may help.